# Java Applets and Firefox unresponsive Error message

Tags: java, debugging, firefox, applet

I have a Java Applet. On IE, it works fine, On Firefox, Firefox frequently given a dialog box saying "The plugin is unresponsive/hung. Do you want to continue waiting for it or kill it?".

In order to troubleshoot, it would be useful to know how firefox detects that the plugin is unresponsive - has Firefox published this info anywhere?

I found this page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins/Out_of_process_plugins/The_plugin_hang_detector

However this talks about killing the plugin & not giving this error message.

Comment: As a note; applet support will not continue on new versions of some browsers(For ex: Chrome). Maybe it is about with that but I think firefox will continue to support. This is not an exact solution; have a look https://support.mozilla.org/tr/questions/1074664, I hope it gaves an idea to solve your problem

Comment: You can try to change **dom.ipc.plugins.java.enabled** using `about:config`. If the problem still exist, Please provide the version of Firefox/JRE.

Answer (score 2):

### Following are additional measures you can take to resolve Unresponsive Script error.

1. Waiting longer for the error to resolve itself automatically
2. Blocking the offending script
3. Yanking the guilty add-ons
4. Disabling the hardware acceleration tool.

> With one of these few steps, you won’t have to worry about the
>   Unresponsive Script error, can continue enjoying your browsing
>   activities on Firefox.

### [Fix Unresponsive Script Error in Firefox are briefly described below:](http://www.reginout.com/nflp/fix-unresponsive-script-error-in-firefox-chrome-ie.html)

### Change Script Runtime Value

In the Firefox configurations you’ll get the script runtime value. You’ll need to modify the default value and change it to “20”.

1. Open Mozilla Firefox.
2. Type “about:config” in the Address Bar.
3. Press ENTER.
4. A warning message will appear. Click `“I’ll be careful, I promise!”`
   link to continue.
5. Double click a string named `“dom.max_script_run_time”`.
6. Replace its value with “20” and press ENTER.

Note: In case the problem still persists you can restore the default value by right clicking the string, selecting “Reset” option.

### Use YesScript Plug-In

1. Install YesScript.
2. Close and re-load Mozilla Firefox.
3. Click the Tools menu, select Add-Ons.
4. Select “YesScript” and click Options.
5. A new dialog will appear. Enter the website URL which displays you
   script error.
6. Click Add button. This will fix Unresponsive Script Error in
   Firefox, Chrome & IE.

### Start Firefox in the Safe Mode

In the safe mode a browser is loaded without loading any add-ons. Start the browser in safe mode to resolve faulty add-ons.

1. Click the Firefox button.
2. Click Help | Restart with add-ons disabled.

Alternatively, you may press Shift key while starting Firefox.

### Disable Hardware Acceleration

Some computers may not support hardware acceleration of the browser. Disable this feature to fix Unresponsive Script Error in Firefox, Chrome & IE.

1. Click the Firefox button, select Options.
2. Click Advanced tab.
3. Uncheck the box “Use hardware acceleration when available”.
4. Close and re-open the browser.

### Restore Default Theme

You might have to restore the default theme. Some of the features of existing theme are not supporting.

1. Click Firefox button, select Add-Ons.
2. Click Appearance tab on the left.
3. Set your default theme.

### Disable Synchronization in Firefox

Do not let firefox synchronize items such as apps, settings, tabs, history, passwords, etc Disable the synchronization feature.

1. Click Firefox button.
2. Select Options.
3. Click the Sync tab.
4. Disable the synchronization feature.

### Resource Link:

1. [How to Stop Script Errors on Firefox](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/stop-script-errors-firefox-48954.html)